# BitmapImage's ImageFailed event and it's exception object

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

```
 var image = new BitmapImage();
     image.ImageFailed += (s, e) => {
       // ...
     };
     image.UriSource = new Uri("someurl", UriKind.Absolute);
```

In the documentation it's mentioned that the ImageFailed event can be raised by:

- File not found.
- Invalid (unrecognized or unsupported) file format.
- Unknown file format decoding error after upload

Is it possible to detect which one of these conditions caused it inside the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, since the event argument is a [ExceptionRoutedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.exceptionroutedeventargs.aspx) which have a [ErrorException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.exceptionroutedeventargs.errorexception.aspx) property, in which you can check for following exception types:

- `SecurityException`
- `FileNotFoundException`
- `NotSupportedException`
- `COMException`

Read the details [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.exceptionroutedeventargs.errorexception.aspx)

Example:

```
var image = new BitmapImage();
image.ImageFailed += (s, e) => 
{
    if (e.ErrorException is FileNotFoundException)
         // File not found.
    else if (e.ErrorException is NotSupportedException)
        // Unknown file format decoding error after upload
    else
        // Really bad stuff happened!    
};
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. Seems like I missed the page, because the docs are divided for SL/WPF etc.

Comment: It would seem the `FileFormatException` isn't available on Silverlight, but the others should be.